# How do I assign a Future<List> return type to a variable?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have created a method that makes API call. It receives and the returns the data as example bellow shows:

```
Future<List<SearchResult>> postCall() async {
  List<SearchResult> searchResult = [];
  ....
  return  searchResult;
}
```

And, I have tried to store the response into the `List` as bellow code shows. But, I have got this error:
`Avalue of type Future<List<SearchResult>> can't be assigned to a variable of type List<sResult>`

I am trying to store the response into list as List is easier for me to loop through the data. Is there an alternative way to store the response in the `List`? or how can I iterate through the nested objects using `FutureBuilder`?

```
List<SearchResult> sResult = [];
sResult = serviceOne.postCall();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should be this, because it is result of `Future`.

```
sResult = await serviceOne.postCall();
```